# Magento configurable product out of stock

Tags: magento

I want to change configurable product to 'out of stock'(this is for a client requirement) when all its associated product stock become 'out of stock'. I think magento automatically doesn't do this. How Can i do this? Do i need to write any custom code?

Comment: You don't required to do custom code.Check product inventory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont think you need to write any custom code for this.
This feature is already provided in magento, if an associated product is out of stock then it would disappear from product options and if all of the associated products are out of stock then the parent configurable product will also be displayed as out of stock. Tested in magento version 1.9 :)